# Vertically centering objects in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I've to align items vertically in flexbox. Here's my code: 
http://pastebin.com/1YKrYxA3

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.flex-conteneur {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1026px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.colone1 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  align-items: center;
}
.colone2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.colone3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.titre {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Arial Black"
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-conteneur">
  <div class="titre">
    Programmation Web : INF2005
  </div>
  <ul class="colone1">
    <li>
      <a href "#">Acceuil</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href "#">Notes de cours</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href "#">Atelirs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href "#">Travaux Pratiques</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="colone2">
    Ce gabarit doit être structuré avec des div et mise en forme avec CSS
  </div>

  <div class="colone3">
    Colone 3 : contenu secondaire
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `align-content` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

`align-content` only affects multi-line flex containers; it aligns the containing lines.

You want `align-items`, which affects the actual flex items.

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your code, there is no `align-content` property anywhere. It doesn't exist in your code.

The [`align-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-content-property) property manages the alignment of multiple lines of flex items along the cross axis of the flex container. This property has no effect on a single line in a flex container.

Although there is no `align-content` there is an [`align-items`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-items-property) declaration.

```
.colone1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The problem, however, is that you've applied the `align-items` property to a flex item, when it only works on a flex container.

If your goal is to vertically center the content of the `ul` with class `colone1`, then you must also apply `display: flex`, so the flex item becomes a flex container, as well.

If your goal is to vertically center the `.colone1`, then you need to apply `align-items: center` to the flex container (`.flex-conteneur`).

Some flex properties only work on flex items. Others only on flex containers. For a listing of properties divided by parent and child see this article: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi there

I've tryed applying the align-items: center to the flex-conteneur.

Doesn't work.
I don't know if something else is in conflict with the attribute maybe ?

Comment: It actually does work, but maybe we're talking about different things here. Can you further describe or maybe post an image of the layout you're trying to achieve?

Comment: my text in the boxes i want them to be centered vertically

Comment: Okay, then you have to apply `display: flex` to each flex item to make it a flex container... http://jsfiddle.net/acjuaes4/

Comment: Oh ok so in order for it to work i need to "create" a 2nd flexbox container in the primary flexbox so i can apply the attributes to it ?

Clever !
I've always got a feeling that vertacly aligning things in HTML and CSS is tricky.

Comment: Yes, you need nested flexboxes because `align-items` and other alignment properties are applied to the flex container *but* work on the flex items.